# MOSFET switch not turning off

Tags: mosfet, switches

I'm having trouble with my circuit. It is supposed to be a load switch to turn on a Wi-Fi module, but it is not working as intended.
The idea is to set WIFI_CTRL to high to turn on WIFI_ENABLE.

The components are:

Q3= [DMP1045UQ](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP1045UQ.pdf)
Q4= [TSM250N02CX](http://www.taiwansemi.com/products/datasheet/TSM250N02CX_A14.pdf)

I tried reducing the resistance of R10 to 1K and even 100 ohm for a stronger pull-up but still WIFI_Enable is just down to 1.5 V.

Can anyone pinpoint my issue or recommend suitable SOT-23 replacements?

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your P channel MOSFET is upside down. And now the P-channel body diode is always in forward biased and turn-on your WIFI_ENABLE regardless Q4 state.

[image: P-MOSFET body diode]

P channel MOSFET source need to be connected to VCC3

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a pull-down resistor on the gate terminal of Q4. Without this resistor small charges at the gate can keep the MOSFET turned on.