# NMOS T3 always on

Tags: transistors, debugging

[image]

Hi all, i have this circuit that is actually really simple. when I came to do the prototype, something that i can't explain happens.

the transistor T3 is always on even if i do not connect the supply VG1, how this is possible?

i'm sure about the pinout, checked several times. also i'm using a bjt for pnp, so no body diode that accidentally turns the transistor on should be there.

some help?

Comment: But did you herd about the MOSFET body diode? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368171/mosfet-switch-not-turning-off/368174#368174

Answer (score 1):

The [2N6755](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/50059/FAIRCHILD/2N6755.html) \$V_{DSS}\$ (maximum drain-source voltage) is spec'd at 60v, but you are applying +/-80v.

\$V_{SD}\$ or diode forward voltage is listed as 1.7v, implying that these also have an intrinsic body diode to consider.