# LTSPICE P-Channel MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

I'm learning LTSPICE and am very confused by the results coming from playing around with P-channel MOSFETs.

I created a very complete test of P-channel and N-channel MOSFETs, and all the N-channel results make sense to me, but can someone please explain what's going on with the P-channel?

[image: P-channel experimental setup]

M1 behaves as a forward biased diode with a voltage drop of about 0.105 V (seems small but believable).

M2, which according to my understanding of P-FETs should behave like a closed circuit, behaves virtually identically to M1.

M3 and M4 are also identical, and the results are:

[image: M3 and M4 results]

M4, which is likely the most useful configuration, has a waveform that makes sense, but the numbers don't make any sense. Shouldn't this work as a switch, meaning that the voltage should go between roughly 0 and roughly 20, not 19.898 and 19.895? (R_ds,on = 0.035 ohms) And M3 is the same - is that okay?

Lool I was fighting with a more complicated simulation all day and finally decided to go back to the basics, and now I'm just more confused...

Comment: The P=channel MOSFET are similar to PNP. Do you know how to use a PNP transistor? Only M2 and M4 are properelty connected. But in M4 you need to change the V2 voltage swing up to 20V. 5V is too small to Turn-OFF the P-MOS. In general P-MOS is a high side device. The source terminal must be connected to +Vsupply. And the be able to turn-on the P-MOS the gate terminal voltage must be lower than source voltage by a Vgs(th) voltage or more (0V). And to Turn_OFF the P-MOS the gate voltage must be equal to +Vspply or Vg > Vsupply - Vgs(th)   And M2 and M3 conduct current due to the Body diode.

Comment: Body diode https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368171/mosfet-switch-not-turning-off/368174#368174  And datasheet http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AON6407.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'm assuming in the last sentence you meant to say M1 and M3 conduct current due to the body diode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't this work as a switch, meaning that the voltage should go between roughly 0 and roughly 20, not 19.898 and 19.895?

If you want to switch the PMOS off, you need to drive the gate very close to the source. So you need the pulse amplitude to be ~20 V, rather than 5 V.

As it is, you are only testing the difference between the transistor being very strongly "on" (\$V_{gs}=-20\ V\$) and being just slightly less strongly on (\$V_{gs}=-15\ V\$).

To put the MOSFET into cut-off mode, you want \$V_{gs} > -0.3\ V\$ (based on the datasheet minimum \$V_{gs}({\rm th})\$).

Comment: Ah thanks! Was playing with it between 18 and 19 V and watching it in the non-linear region, around 19 V it starts working as I expected.